# How to correct index and current date

Tags: php, codeigniter, charts, highcharts

I have the following error with this highcharts chart library.
I need to update the date to the current one and that the date of the corresponding day appears in the index.

just change from Highcharts.chart to Highcharts.stockChart. (Attached image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAKV3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lbUj.png)

from here the data and graph are brought

```
function datagrafico(base_url){
                                        
 $.ajax({
   url: base_url + "index.php/Admin/getDataDias",
   type:"POST",
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data){
      var dias = new Array();
      var montos = new Array();
      $.each(data,function(key, value){
           dias.push(value.fecha_actualizacion);
           valor = Number(value.monto);
           montos.push(valor);
        });
        graficar(dias,montos);
        }
       });
      }

function graficar(dias, montos){
                                        
                                        
    Highcharts.stockChart('grafico', {
      chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
       text: 'Monto acumulado por ventas diarias'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: dias,
        crosshair: true
        },
                                        
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Monto Acumulado (Colombiano)'
        }
    },
                                        
    tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">Monto: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} Colombiano</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series:{
                dataLabels:{
                        enabled:true,
                        formatter:function(){
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y)
                }

            }
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
            inputPosition: {
                align: 'right',
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'dias',
            data: montos

        }]
    });
```

controller:

```
public function getDataDias(){
        
        $resultados = $this->model_venta->montos();
        echo json_encode($resultados);
    }
```

and model:

```
public function montos(){
    $this->db->select("fecha_actualizacion, SUM(total) as monto");
    $this->db->from("venta");
    $this->db->where("pago_id","2");
    $this->db->where("estado","1");
    $this->db->group_by('DATE(fecha_actualizacion)');
    $this->db->order_by('DATE(fecha_actualizacion)');
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you change Highcharts to Higcharts Stock, they are similar but building charts from other API. Please have a look at the Stock [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis) they, do not have categories options inside xAxis.

The millisecond format of data is standard in the Highcharts Stock axis, you need to change data format to put it in the chart.

```
   series: [{
     type: 'column',
     data: [
       [1592314200000, 165428800],
       [1592400600000, 114406400],
       [1592487000000, 96820400],
       [1592573400000, 264476000],
       [1592832600000, 135445200],
       [1592919000000, 212155600]
     ],
   }]
```

Under are Highchart and Higcharts Stock examples to compare of building.

Highchart Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sw3qr5p9/

Highchart Stock Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/drnup1tx/